# to read email password from text file and sigin using selenium rc and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, junit4

I have a email.txt file where I am storing all email address and password written in java and by running test through selenium rc. My question is that selenium .clicks sigIn then it should go to the text file email.txt and use one of the email address and password to signIn and second time when I run the selenium tests then it should not pick up the first time the email and password it has used for signing in.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding about your question.You want to use all those email id and password one by one.

So for that scenario you better go with data driven testing.If you are using Junit use Parameterized runner to do the same.

If you are working with TestNG there is annotation known as @Dataprovider for data driven testing.

In this case your test case will be called n number of times for n different values of your test data(EmailID and password here in ur case) and eveery time new data will be used in that test.